# Programmatically tell the difference between routes in Angular 2 component

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently i have 2 separate routes that point to 2 components that are more or less the exact same. Id like to just combine them into one component so i dont have to maintain 2 components that are the same. Logically what i want to do is very simple, I just need to know the route.

Here are the 2 routes i have.

```
{ path: 'server/:key/:id', component: ScheduleComponent },
{ path: 'server/:key/editschedule/:id', component: EditScheduleComponent },
```

I need to programmatically determine which route is being triggered. It is important because :id is not the same for both. When creating the ID is the parent, when editing the ID is the item itself.

Essentially what i want is

```
if(route == theeditroute) do A;
else do B;
```

Comment: In your example they are different components. If you inherit one class from the other, you can manage the differences with handling params this way too, this would be probably cleaner way to do this than route conditions.

Comment: yea they are different and its a bit annoying having the same code in 2 places, so i want to be rid of it. Inheritance would be clean, but for tiny changes where i could easily put an if, id need to copy the function and modify it slightly

Comment: You can inject the router and subscribe to events and get the route information from the event, or you can add data to the route and get it from the injected `ActivatedRoute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be figured out from `ActivatedRoute` service:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

Either the entire path can be matched from [`routeConfig`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#routeConfig-anchor):

```
if (this.route.routeConfig.path === 'server/:key/editschedule/:id') ...
```

Or the required url segment can be matched from [`url` array](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html#!#url-anchor)

```
const segmentNames = this.route.snapshot.url.map(({ path }) => path);

if (segmentNames.includes('editschedule')) ...
```

A cleaner way to do this is purely OOP approach. Since there already are two different components for these routes, this can be efficiently solved with inheritance.

Either both components can inherit from base class or one component can inherit from another.

```
@Injectable()
class BaseScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(...) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.doStuff();
  }

  doStuff() { ... }
  ...
}

@Component({ ... }
ScheduleComponent {
  doStuff() {
    // do common stuff if necessary
    super.doStuff();

    // do route-dependent stuff
    ...
  }
}
```

Depending on how these two components differ and how specific `doStuff` is, `doStuff` can be omitted and `ngOnInit` method can be extended or overridden directly.

Answer (score 1):

If these two components are almost the same you can route to one shared component and inject ActivatedRoute to the component constructor. Do your login ngOnInit of the component based on ActivatedRoute. You can easily add an indicator about type of route using data that will be populated on ActivatedRoute.

```
{  path: 'server/:key/:id', 
   data: {edit: false}, 
   component: ScheduleComponent 
 },
 { path: 'server/:key/editschedule/:id', 
   data: {edit: true},  
   component: ScheduleComponent 
 },
```

Here is the component part:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: 
  ActivatedRoute) {
 }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isEdit = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['edit'];
}
```

Comment: This seems nice and clean. How would i check whether edit is true or false from ngOnInit?